# Production and Research overflow in Civilization 5

Tags: civilization-5

What happens with overflowing research or production in Civilization 5?

If you produce more research in one turn than is needed for the current technology, is the research surplus carried over to the next researched technology? The same question applies to overflowing production.

Do I have to micromanage production and research to avoid wasting it?

Comment: Interesting - I never hit his problem with research - how do you hit this? Most research I do takes a couple of rounds, so waste should be really limited?

Comment: @Martin Say a tech requires 500 beakers, and you are generating 80 beakers per turn.  After 6 turns you have accumulated 480.  On the 7th turn you get the tech, but your progress towards the next tech starts at 0.  So effectively you lost 60 beakers.

Comment: Hmmm ... indeed this is a 10% waste over the tech cycle. Guess I never bothered, but I never played difficulty > Prince, so it didn't matter that much I guess.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of the 12/15/10 patch, research should overflow as it did in previous civs.  Any extra beakers that weren't needed to learn your tech will be applied towards your next one.  Carry over on production still does not overflow.  It can be abused to some extent, so they may have intentionally eliminated it.

Answer (score 1):

As of the 12/15 patch, research carries over between scientific advancements, identically to the past Civ games.

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions, surplus research and production were carried across to your next tech/build. I haven't investigated this in V, but I haven't heard that it has changed, nor can see any reason why it might be changed.

OK: It seems I am wrong - for now at least:
http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=392436